# Unzipping File From AWS S3 via Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gzip

I have this code that pushes a file into S3 as a gzip. But when pulling it back down, I cannot figure out how to unzip it and it and store the content as a variable.

```
def push_to_s3(args,args,args):

    data = response.json()
    data = str(data.get("actual_data"))

    inmemory = io.BytesIO() 
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=inmemory, mode='wb') as fh:

        with io.TextIOWrapper(fh, encoding='utf-8',errors='replace') as wrapper:
            wrapper.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False,indent=2))
    inmemory.seek(0)  
    cv.s3_resource.Object(args, args + ) + '.json.gz').upload_fileobj(inmemory)     

    inmemory.close()
```

Below is where I am trying to pull the file down, read the content and store it as a value for later use.

```
obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket = Bucket, Key = key)

content = obj['Body'].read()

print(content)
```

**I just need to translate content back into text and assign it to a variable , but I cannot figure out how (it is just a 9 digit number)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
>>> with gzip.open(obj['Body']) as f:
        content = f.read().decode('utf-8')
>>> content
'"186686935"'
```